# How do I set .requireForce to false in git?

Tags: git, shell, github

I'm trying to get rid of a few untracked files that I don't want in my GitHub using the shell. I'm trying to use the command `git clean -d` to do this. However, I get the error message

> fatal: clean.requireForce defaults to true and neither -i, -n, nor -f
>   given

whenever I try to do so. It seems that if I change this simple setting I can solve this problem; however, I do not know how to do so.

Comment: It's `clean.requireForce`, not just `.requireForce`; but in general you should not set this. Just use the `-f` option when you mean to run `git clean`. Making it default to true means Git will remove all untracked files whenever you ask it, without first confirming; this cannot be undone.

Answer (score 3):

```
git config --local clean.requireForce false
```

Answer (score 1):

As clean is dangerous operarion, it does not do anything unless you specify `-f` argument. You could also specify `-n` to only list files to be deleted. You could set up a default mode to not type it in command line, but by my opinion it is not a good thing. Instead just usevthe argument explicitly

So, first use command

```
git clean -d -n
```

to see thevlistvof files to be deleted, then

```
git clean -d -f
```

to actually delete them

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your advice and helpful answer.